# Animate div partially out of frame, no scrollbars

Tags: css

I want to animate a div with content, so that its top left corner would be say 30px from the right edge of the window, but the browser doesn't detect it as something that needs to be scrolled to. how can this be done?

Comment: Make a wrapper with `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the div's parent (outer) has overflow set to hidden

```
<div id='outer' style='overflow:hidden;'>
    <div id='yourdiv'></div>
</div>
```